# Visual Studio Editor Errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't know why but my Visual Studio Editor showing me continuous errors like this kind of:
[image]

Today I am getting this continuously, I have installed Visual Studio multiple times but the same problem is coming again and again.

At present, I have installed Visual Studio Version 8.9.5.4
One more thing, I am using iMac with Mac OS as the operating system.

How to remove these errors?

Comment: Do you have the workload "Game development with Unity" installed with Visual Studio?

Comment: Sometimes this also happens when there is a missing `using`.

Comment: I don't like another editor for C# and Unity HUB by default provides an option for Visual Studio so for many years, I have a habit to work with Visual Studio.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes All scripts showing the same error that is the main problem.

Comment: You might get a clue from the error description in the Error List window?--or by hovering your mouse over the error?

Comment: Close down Unity, Unity Hub and visual studios. Then try deleting your VS folder in the project folder of your game. Then open everything back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after trying hard from yesterday, today I have a solution for this problem and I was getting the same kind of problem with all scripts of the project.

Within Package Manager for Visual Studio Editor, there is some update available so that I have done it and the problem gets solved.
Within the following image, I have shown the exact place.

[image]

After this, I have opened the Visual Studio editor multiple times and it does not have any problem.

I hope for any other person if Visual Studio Editor is creating a problem then this solution becomes helpful because Visual Studio Editor is directly attached with Unity Editor.

Comment: I hope this answer becomes useful to many users for whom Visual Studio stopped to identify Unity Syntaxes. Many people thinking here this question is irrelevant but I faced this problem multiple times when I was using Unity with Visual Studio and at last, I found the solution. If this solution work for you then please like this question :)